# { returning a string from a function } EVAL: variable has no value

Tags: common-lisp

I'm unable to print the return value of return-str.

```
; return-str.lisp
(defun ask-for-input(str)
  (princ str)
  (let ((cmd (read-line)))
    cmd))
(defun return-str()
  (let ((data-str (ask-for-input "enter a string")))
    (data-str)))
(princ return-str)
```

Executing the code above with clisp, I got:

```
$ clisp return-str.lisp
*** - EVAL: variable RETURN-STR has no value
```

Please help me on how to properly return a string from return-str.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parentheses are incorrect in a couple of places.

- `(data-str)` should be replaced with `data-str` because `data-str` is not a function.
- `(princ return-str)` should be replaced with `(princ (return-str))` because `return-str` is a function.

Comment: That was fast and fixed my problem! Thank you.